# Redirect in PHP regarding on session variable

Tags: php, session, redirect

when someone visit "other page" is redirected on index.php,
but when after that tries to open "other page" again is redirected.

Please help, because the code below doesnt work.

on page index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['INDEX']="1";
?>
```

on all "other pages"

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['INDEX']!="1"){
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you adding `session_start();` at top on all other pages ?

Comment: Have you started the session on other pages?

Comment: u've missed `session_start();` in "other pages" anyway use `.htaccess` to do what you want

Answer (score 4):

Add `session_start();` at the top of other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add session_start(); on all pages where need to check if any session value exist.

change your code:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['INDEX']!="1"){
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

with

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['INDEX']!="1"){
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```